# Is there a single device that allows me to switch between two computers for all screens and keyboard/mouse/etc?

Tags: multiple-monitors, switch, docking-stations, splitters

So I have my work laptop and my (gaming) PC both connected to 2 monitors. My dream scenario is to press a single button and have my 2 monitors, keyboard, mouse, printer, and any other USB device switch between the 2 different computers.

I do not want a KVM solution where both computers are being used simultaneously. I need full disconnect since I want all my screens dedicated to a single machine at a time.

Currently, I am using [this as my screen splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KC65224) and [this as my USB splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TS5JNT3). This is working great, but it takes 3 button presses (each screen and then the USB splitter) to switch everything over and cable management is a joke.

Ideally, I want a legit docking station like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087WKQ8SW), but be able to toggle which active host I am using. Does such device exist? Even if there are multiple connectors, I just want to click one button and have decent cable management!!

Comment: I don't see how a KVM doesn't support the use case you are describing. There are several Dual monitor KVM switches that have multi monitor support where both screens are showing one device

Comment: Make your printer a network printer, and then both PC can access the printer whenever they want.  No button clicking or other dumb sharing methods.